# What is a single word for everything going your way?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I need an adjective that conveys the meaning of things going the way you want them to.
For example if you are a king you would want everything during your reign to go your way.

> When I am king, I want a ______ reign.

Comment: I want a ***smooth*** reign.

Answer (score 3):

**auspicious**

2. favored by fortune; prosperous; fortunate.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/auspicious

Comment: That doesn't mean things happened the way OP wanted. Maybe the king is religious and when things didn't go his way, his counsel of ministers told him that it was auspicious and he just had to accept it. He wouldn't need to be favored by fortune if things went his way.

Comment: @vickyace, I think you're confusing auspicious with fateful. If the king is favored by fortune as defined by him (since he is the one making the statement), I do believe that things necessarily are going his way.

Answer (score 1):

When something isn't going the way you want, it opposes you. When nothing opposes you, you are *unopposed*. So you might say

> When I am king, I want an **unopposed** reign.

Alternatively, your could use **unobstructed, uncontested**, or  **unchallenged**.

This covers those thing one would explicitly want, as you say in your opening sentence.

However, if you want to go beyond what you openly want, then better than being unopposed would be that everything fortuitously falls in place. (It would be like winning the lottery when you didn't even by a ticket! Who wouldn't want that? But it's not really what most people seriously want in the sense that they might expect it to happen.) For that, you might say you want a *charmed* reign, where charmed means "marked by good fortune or privilege" ([Dictionary.com #1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/charmed)). But *charmed* is not a commonly used word today, so you might simply say

> I want a reign favored by fortune.

or

> I want a prosperous reign.

This is where *auspicious* comes in. It is good fortune not just for what is wanted, but for everything else, as well. But I don't think, based on your first sentence, this is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **beneficent**

1. doing good or causing good to be done; conferring benefits; kindly in action or purpose.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/beneficent

or **thriving** which has multiple meanings which seem relevant

1. to prosper; be fortunate or successful.
2. to grow or develop vigorously; flourish:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thriving

Answer (score 0):

[***trouble-free***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trouble-free)

> Not causing any problems or difficulties.

*(Collins)*

> When I am king, I want a trouble-free reign.